# How does git interpret a colon followed by a path?

Tags: git

I was toying with a syntax to refer a commit by its commit message and then I got this error:

```
$ git show :/A
fatal: ambiguous argument ':/A': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

The error message is pretty clear about how to solve it, but I haven't found any documentation explaining how does git interpret a colon followed by a path. Only if followed by a branch name. 
Can you please give me some references to learn more about this?

Answer (score 3):

It's actually a bit trickier than you might expect, as `:/A` could be *three* things.

There are multiple different bits of Git documentation that talk about this, but there are two main places to look:

- [The gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) describes how `:`-prefixes work when something is a *revision specifier*.
- [The gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) defines how `:`-prefixes work when something is a *pathspec*.

When it's just a file name, `:/A` just means the file named `:/A`.

As a *pathspec*, `:/A` uses the "magic signature" character `/`, no terminating `:`, and the name `A`, so it refers to the file named `A` in the *root directory* (of the repository or work-tree), rather than the file `:/A` in the *current* directory.

As a *revision specifier*, `:/A` searches commit messages, and `A` becomes a regular expression (although in this case it's a trivial regex that just matches the letter `A`):

> ... This name returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from any ref, including HEAD.

Using the `--` you'll force Git to treat it as a *pathspec*, where you may want to add `:(literal)` in front to protect it from interpretation.

Comment: What do you mean with "no terminating :" ? I didn't understand what does ' : ' do in a pathspec

Comment: The pathspec section says *A pathspec that begins with a colon `:` has special meaning. In the short form, the leading colon : is followed by zero or more "magic signature" letters (which optionally is terminated by another colon `:`) ...* So `:/:` has the optional terminating colon.

Comment: It goes on to say: *In the long form, the leading colon `:` is followed by an open parenthesis `(`, a comma-separated list of zero or more "magic words", and a close parentheses `)`, and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path.* I get tripped-up by this, writing, e.g., `:(top,icase):path/name` before remembering that there's *no* optional terminating colon, so that this tries to match `/:path/name` ignoring case, rather than matching `path/name` ignoring case.